# Not able to read uni-codes characters in java

Tags: java, unicode, tinymce

Not able to read uni-codes characters in java.

```
    String inputLine = "&#1578;&#1575;&#1585;&#1610;&#1582;&#1575;&#1604;&#1575;&#1605;&#1578;&#1581;&#1575;&#1606;"
```

When I try to write this line to a text file with

```
    String tmp = new String(inputLine.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    File file = new File("/home/gaurav/input.txt");

    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(content);
    bw.close();
```

Text file still contains the same text.

NOTE:
The input line content is submitted by browser while i type below text in a text-box(Tinymc Editor) that supports multilingual text. It may contains Chinese, french and other language text.

تاريخالامتحان

Answer (score 1):

```
String inputLine = "&#1578;...
```

That's an HTML or XML numeric character reference. It only means `ت` in an HTML or XML document. Everywhere else, ampersand does not have magic powers and it just means an ampersand, a hash sign, the number 1578 and a semicolon.

You have used it in a Java string literal. Java is not HTML. You're writing the results to a text file. Plain text isn't HTML either. So at no point does the ampersand gain any special meaning.

Java has its own way of referencing a character from its number, which is backslash-U escapes. You want character `ت`, U+062A Arabic Letter Teh, so the format is:

```
String inputLine = "\u062A...
```

(Hexadecimal 0x062A = decimal 1578.)

Having got Arabic into your string you now have to get it into a file. To do this you have to choose what encoding the file is going to be in. You probably want UTF-8, though there are other possible encodings that can accommodate Arabic characters. Unfortunately...

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
```

...JAVA has a load of poorly-defined interfaces that allow you not to choose an encoding, and instead plump for the ‘default encoding’. This encoding varies from machine to machine and is almost never anything you want; chances are on your machine it can't contain Arabic characters at all.

You should never use the default encoding in Java, which is why it's so unfortunate that Java's interfaces and tutorials encourage you to use it all the time. The `FileWriter` class is the worst of the lot because it *only* allows you to use the hated default encoding. So never use `FileWriter`, which is only a lame shortcut for a `OutputStreamWriter` over a `FileOutputStream` anyway. With an `OutputStreamWriter` you can choose what encoding you really want.

```
OutputStreamWriter fw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "utf-8");
```

By the way you shouldn't do this:

```
String tmp = new String(inputLine.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

This would encode `inputLine` to bytes using the default encoding, then decode the resulting bytes back to a string using UTF-8. That would only do anything useful if the original string had been badly misdecoded, and even then it's not something you should rely on because the it depends on the horrible unreliable default encoding. Don't fall into the superstition of peppering your code with pasted encode/decode cycles. Much better to just get the characters right in the first place.

You probably also don't need the `createNewFile` bit. `FileOutputStream` will start writing at the start of a new file already (unless you pass `append=true` to it).